# read .txt files more memory efficient c++

Tags: c++, memory-management, cin

I am working on a neural network in C++ and want it to train on the MNIST training set. The .txt file that contains all the inputs and the respective outputs that are wanted is 301819KB in size. I am currently trying to read them with the lines

```
vector<vector<float> > inp;
    vector<int> out;
    vector<float> row;
    float buf;
    int bufl;
    for (int outer = 0; outer < 60000; ++outer) {
        for (int reader = 0; reader < 784; ++reader) {
            cin >> buf;
            row.push_back(buf);
        }
        inp.push_back(row);
    }
    for (int label = 0; label < 60000; ++label) {
        cin >> bufl;
        out.push_back(bufl);
    }
```

however when i compile it using

```
g++ -o nn main.cpp
```

and then run it using

```
nn < out.txt
```

after a few seconds there comes an error which says: out of memory. Is there either a way to make my reading of the .txt file to the vector more memory efficient or somehow allow the program to acces more memory? the programm only uses about 1.2GB of memory (which i think is still pretty memory inefficient for just reading 300MB of input file) so I would still have plenty of memory to use (I have 16GB)

Comment: You're never resetting `row` so it keeps growing, leading to quadratic memory usage.

Comment: Hint: Move `row` inside of your loop.

Comment: Note: `vector`s of `vector`s can be pretty inefficient, especially if the inner `vector` is short, due to poor spatial locality. Looks like you have a rectangular matrix here with a fixed size inner `vector`. Consider using `std::array` instead so you get a contiguous block of memory.

Comment: It's good practice to declare your variables nest to where they are used rather than at the top of the function, that way you would declare the row variable in the loop and wouldn't have had this problem.

Answer (score 1):

As the comment says, `row` never gets cleared out so it grows forever. Here is the fixed version with a few optimizations for the vectors:

```
    vector<vector<float> > inp;
    vector<int> out;
    vector<float> row;

    // reserve known sizes
    constexpr size_t kNumSamples = 60000;
    constexpr size_t kRowLength = 784;
    inp.reserve(kNumSamples); 
    row.reserve(kRowLength);
    out.reserve(kNumSamples); 

    float buf;
    int bufl;
    for (int outer = 0; outer < kNumSamples; ++outer) {
        for (int reader = 0; reader < kRowLength; ++reader) {
            cin >> buf;
            row.push_back(buf);
        }

        // move the row into the input vector, this will also reset the row
        inp.push_back(std::move(row));
    }
    for (int label = 0; label < kNumSamples; ++label) {
        cin >> bufl;
        out.push_back(bufl);
    }
```

There are other changes you could make as well (like declaring your variables inside the scope that they are used), but to match the input code as much as possible I've left them out.

Comment: Typically an moved-from object is left in a safe-but-unspecified state and a brief perusal of the Standard and cppreference didn't pop up an exception otr guarantee of better behaviiour. You'll probably get a clearing of the `vector`, but I don't think you can guarantee it. But what I am quite sure that if you move from from a `vector`, the `reserve`ed storage will be gone. re`reserving`is almost certainly necessary, and if you have to re-reserve, might ass well re-allocate and `>>` right into the `vector`'s elements.

Comment: why do you use size_t instead of for example just an integer?

Comment: I get some errors when I run the code using g++ the errors i get are:
parse error before `kNumSamples'
kNumSamples' undeclared (first use this function)
(Each undeclared identifier is reported only once
for each function it appears in.)
`kRowLength' undeclared (first use this function)
confused by earlier errors, bailing out

Comment: `vector` can't deal with negative numbers (can you imagine a `vector` size of -10?), so you'll find it returns nothing but unsigned integers. And they are darn big unsigned integers. Say you have a an `int` and that `int` is 32 bits and you have a `vector` with, say, five billion items in it. You're gonna have a rough time.

Comment: `size_t` is a unsigned integer type guaranteed to be able to represent the size of any object that the C++ implementation can support. It might be too big, but it'll probably be what's being used by `vector` under the all of the type aliassing.